# Prime power factorization of $10^n+1$

Tags: number-theory, divisibility

I have bee trying to prove/disprove the statement, $$\text{Let}\; 10^n+1 = p_{k}^{\;\alpha_k}p_{k-1}^{\;\alpha_{k-1}}\dots p_0, \text{where each}\; p_i \;\text{is a distinct prime.} 
\text{Then}\; \lnot\exists \alpha_i \geq 3\;\text{such that}\; p_i^{\;\alpha_i}|(10^n+1).$$

I have tried a few, things, such as proving the statement for the case $$a_i=3$$ just to see how it might look in general, however I must be missing something. I also checked up to $10^{72}+1$ to see if there were any accessible counter-examples, however my computer is rather limited, so I could check no further.

I was thinking this might be easiest by contradiction and so I started by assuming $$p^3\mid(10^n+1) \iff 10^n \equiv -1 \pmod {p^3},$$ and by the hypothesis, we also have: $$10^n \equiv -1 \pmod p.$$

I'm at a loss, as I really cannot see anything that might help prove/disprove this. Could someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are trying to prove is false, I'm afraid, since

$$7^3 \mid 10^{147}+1,$$
and there are many other examples, such as:

$$13^3\mid 10^{507}+1.$$

It is quite easy to find these things even with a limited computer using software such as [pari/gp](http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/download.html), which is free and is designed for number-theoretic investigations.

Comment: Ah thank you. As I mentioned, I was not able to check that high for a counter example, and so I could not really find a way to disprove it.